# ¿Por que no me aparece la ventana modal ni la vista previa de mis imagenes?

Tags: javascript, html

necesito ayuda con mi codigo ya que estoy haciendo un sistema de facturación y en el modulo de productos estoy presentando fallas, ya que estoy haciendo una ventana modal al momento que se le da agregar y la misma no me aparece, como tampoco en el modulo de registrar producto me aparece la vista previa de la foto en el div, le remitire el codigo que tengo hasta ahora

```
    LISTA DE PRODUCTOS

    <?php 

session_start();


include "conexion.php";


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">      
    <title>Lista de Productos</title>   
    <?php include "includes/script.php";?>          
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>      
    
</head>
    

    <body>
<?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
    <section id="container">        
    <h1>Lista de Productos </h1>

    <a href="registro_producto.php" class=btn_new>Crear producto</a>    
    <form action="buscar_producto.php" method="get" class="form_search">
    <input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar">

    
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn_search">
</form>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th> 
                <th>Descripcion</th>    
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Existencia</th> 
                <th>Proveedor</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
               <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            
            //*PAGINADOR *//

            $sql_registre = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM producto WHERE estatus = 1");
            $result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_registre);
            $total_registro = $result_register['total_registro'];

            $por_pagina = 4;

            if(empty($_GET['pagina']))
            {
                $pagina = 1;

            }else
            {
                $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
            }

            $desde = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;
            $total_paginas = ceil($total_registro / $por_pagina);

            $query =mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT p.codproducto, p.precio, p.descripcion, p.existencia,pr.proveedor, p.foto FROM producto p
             INNER JOIN proveedor pr ON p.proveedor= pr.codproveedor WHERE p.estatus = 1  
                ORDER BY p.codproducto DESC LIMIT $desde, $por_pagina");
             mysqli_close($conection);

            $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            if ($result > 0 ){

                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                if ($data['foto'] != 'img_producto.png') {
                    $foto = 'img/uploads/'.$data['foto'];
                }else
                {

                $foto = 'img/'.$data['foto'];   
                        
                }//Cierre del else
                

                ?>  


                <tr>
                
                <td><?php echo $data["codproducto"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["descripcion"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["precio"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["existencia"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["proveedor"];?></td>
                <td class = "img_producto"><img src="<?php echo $foto; ?>" alt="<?php echo $data['descripcion'];?>"></td>

                
                <td>

                <?php if($_SESSION['rol'] == 1 || $_SESSION['rol'] == 2){ ?>            


                <a class="link_add add_product" product= "<?php echo $data["codproducto"];?>" href="#">Agregar</a>
                |
                <a class="link_edit" href="editar_producto.php?id=<?php echo $data["codproducto"];?>">Editar</a>                
                |           
                <a class ="link_delete" href="eliminar_producto.php?id=<?php echo $data["codproducto"];?>">Eliminar</a>                         
                                
                </td>

                <?php  }  ?>
            </tr>

                 
         <?php
                
      }


}
   

   ?>
                                        

            
        </table>
        
        <div class="paginador">
        
        <ul>
            
        <?php 

        if ($pagina != 1) {

        ?>
        
        <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo 1;?>"></a></li> 
        <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina  = 1;?>"></a></li>  

        <?php 

        }

        for ($i=1; $i <= $total_paginas; $i++ ) {  
        if ($i == $pagina) {
        echo '<li class="pageSelected">'.$i.'</li>';
        }else
        {
        echo '<li><a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';    
        }

        }

        if($pagina != $total_paginas)
        {
        ?>
        
        <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina = 1;?>"></a></li>
        <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $total_paginas;?>"></a></li>        
        }

        <?php } ?>              
    

        </ul>   

        </div>




        
    </section>
    <?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

El codigo que antecede es el de la lista de productos, como podran ver yo tengo otro archivo php que se llama script el cual incluye todo como es el css, javascript y con ese archivo lo estoy llamando en el proyecto, ahora le remitire dicho archivo para que vean como es su programación

```
SCRIPT.PHP
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">    
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="js/functions-1.js"></script>
```

Les remitire el archivo de registro_producto.php

```
REGISTRO DE PRODUCTO

<?php

session_start();
if($_SESSION['rol'] != 1 and $_SESSION['rol'] != 2)  
{
header("location: index.php ");
}

include "conexion.php";

if(!empty($_POST))
   { 

    

    $alert= '';
    if(empty($_POST['proveedor']) ||  empty($_POST['producto']) ||  empty($_POST['precio']) || empty($_POST['cantidad']))

    {
    $alert = "<script language=\"JavaScript1.2\" src=\"js/usuario_yacreado.js\"></script>";
  }else {   
    $proveedor   = $_POST['proveedor'];
    $producto   = $_POST['producto'];
    $precio = $_POST['precio'];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
    $usuario_id  = $_SESSION['idUser'];


    $foto = $_FILES['foto'];
    $nombre_foto = $foto['name'];
    $type = $foto['type'];
    $url_temp = $foto['tmp_name'];

    $imgProducto = 'img_producto.png';

    if($nombre_foto != '')
    {
      $destino = 'img/uploads/';
      $img_nombre = 'img_'.md5(date('d-m-Y H:m:s'));
      $imgProducto = $img_nombre.'jpg';
      $src = $destino.$imgProducto;


    }


$query_insert = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO producto (proveedor, descripcion, precio, existencia, usuario_id, foto) VALUES ('$proveedor', '$producto','$precio','$cantidad','$usuario_id', '$imgProducto')");
if ($query_insert) {

  if($nombre_foto != '')
  {

  move_uploaded_file($url_temp, $src);  
  }

    $alert = "<script language=\"JavaScript1.2\" src=\"js/usuario_creado.js\"></script>";
  }else {
    $alert = "<script language=\"JavaScript1.2\" src=\"js/error_alcrear.js\"></script>";
  }
  }


   
   

   }
     
?>



<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <?php include "includes/script.php";?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <title>Jose Mari C.A - Registro de Productos</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php include "includes/header.php";?>
<section id = "container"> 

<div class = "form_register">

<h1>Registro Producto</h1>
<hr>
<div class = "alert">
    
<?php 


echo isset($alert)? $alert :'';

?>

</div>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="proveedor">Proveedor</label>

<?php

$query_proveedor = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT codproveedor, proveedor FROM proveedor WHERE estatus = 1 ORDER BY proveedor ASC");
$result_proveedor = mysqli_num_rows($query_proveedor);
mysqli_close($conection);

?>

<select name="proveedor" id="proveedor">
<?php

if($result_proveedor > 0) 
{

if($result_proveedor > 0)
{
  while($proveedor = mysqli_fetch_array($query_proveedor)) 
  {
    ?>

  <option value="<?php echo $proveedor['codproveedor'];?>"><?php echo $proveedor['proveedor'];?></option>  
    <?php
  }
} 
}

  
?>


</select>

<label for="producto">Producto</label>
<input type="text" name="producto" id="producto" placeholder="Nombre del Producto">

<label for="precio">Precio</label>
<input type="number" name="precio" id="precio" placeholder="Precio del Producto">

<label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
<input type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad del Producto">

    <div class="photo">
    <label for="foto">Foto</label>
    <div class="prevPhoto">
    <span class="delPhoto notBlock">X</span>
    <label for="foto"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="upimg">
    <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
    </div>
    <div id="form_alert"></div>
    </div>



<button type = "submit" class = "btn_save">Guardar Producto</button>


</form>

</div>

</section>




<?php include "includes/footer.php";?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Como podran ver el codigo que antecede, yo tengo un div con la clase photo, el cual se encarga de mostrarme la vista previa de la foto que se cargue (el cual inserta a la perfección) pero sin mostrarme la vista previa, ahora le remitire el archivo de javascript para que vean como funciona mi javascript

```
FUNCTIONS-1.JS

(document).ready(function(){

    
           
    $("#foto").on("change",function(){
        var uploadFoto = document.getElementById("foto").value;
        var foto       = document.getElementById("foto").files;
        var nav = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var contactAlert = document.getElementById('form_alert');
            
            if(uploadFoto !='')
            {
                var type = foto[0].type;
                var name = foto[0].name;
                if(type != 'image/jpeg' && type != 'image/jpg' && type != 'image/png')
                {
                    contactAlert.innerHTML = '<p class="errorArchivo">El archivo no es válido.</p>';                        
                    $("#img").remove();
                    $(".delPhoto").addClass('notBlock');
                    $('#foto').val('');
                    return false;
                }else{  
                        contactAlert.innerHTML='';
                        $("#img").remove();
                        $(".delPhoto").removeClass('notBlock');
                        var objeto_url = nav.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
                        $(".prevPhoto").append("<img id='img' src="+objeto_url+">");
                        $(".upimg label").remove();
                        
                    }
              }else{
                alert("No selecciono foto");
                $("#img").remove();
              }              
    });



    $('.delPhoto').click(function(){
        $('#foto').val('');
        $(".delPhoto").addClass('notBlock');
        $("#img").remove();

    });

 $('.addproduct').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var producto = $(this).attr('product');
    alert(producto);
});
 

});
```

Como pueden notar en este ultimo codigo, hago uso del jquery con eventos y cuando se le da agregar se supone que deberia de aparecer la modal, pero la misma no aparece, aunque se le de mil veces, no aparece nada, ya he revisado el codigo todo esta en orden no se por que no me quiere funcionar, me dicen que es por la importación de la libreria jQuery, otros dicen que hay que renombrar el archivo, yo ya he probado con todo lo que analiticamente es posible y nada, por tal motivo le estoy mostrando el codigo, para que me den sugerencias o algo, estare muy agradecido!!!

Les pongo el css por si acaso

```
@import url(../fonts/GothamBook.css);
@import url(../fonts/GothamBold.css);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');


/*****************************************************************/

#tbl_list_productos img{
    width: 50px;
}
.imgProductoDelete{
    width: 175px;
}



* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #ededed;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'arial';
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 16px;    
}

h5 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'arial';
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

span {
    font-family: 'GothamBook';
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #492a02;
    height: 35px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.optionsBar {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.optionsBar span {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'GothamBook';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.photouser {
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}

.close {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.optionsBar a {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

nav ul {
    background: #b97903;
    /*background: #05817d;*/
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
}

nav ul>li a {
    position: relative;
}

nav a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: 'GothamBook';
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: background .5s;
    border-right: 1px solid #319B8F;
}

nav .principal>a {
    background: url(../images/arrow_bottom.png) no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-position: 94% center;
    background-size: 10px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

nav li ul {
    /*background: #177470;*/
    background: #c98300;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

nav li ul a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-right: initial;
}

nav li ul a:hover {
    /*background: #2c9595;*/
    background: #c98300;
}

nav li ul li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
    padding: 90px 15px 15px;
}

/*****************************************************************/

.form_register{
    width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
}
.form_register h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #0446d3;
}
hr{
    border:0;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: block;
}
form{
    background: #fff;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    border: 1px;
}
label{
    display: block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family:'GothamBook';
    margin: 15px auto 5px auto;
}
input,select{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 11pt;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #babd04;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button 
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 11pt;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #babd04;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

.btn_save{
    font-size: 12pt;
    background: #12a412;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px; 
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;    
    margin: 15px auto;
}
.alert{
    width: 100px;
    background: #0c62eb;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.msg_error{
    color: aqua;
}
.msg_save{
    color: #010950;
    padding: 12px 20px;
}
.alert p{
    
    padding: 8px;
}

/***** OJO  Estilo de lista de Usuarios*****/
#container h1{
    font-size: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn_new{
display:inline-block;
background: #fbff0991;
color: rgb(14, 226, 14);
padding: 10px 30px;
border-radius: 20px;
margin: 20px;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: 'arial';
    width: 110%; 
}
table th{
        text-align: left;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #12a412;
        color:floralwhite ;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd){
    background: #30f8aba9
    }
    table td{
        padding: 13px;
    }
    .link_edit{ 
        color: #00aae4;
    }
    .link_delete{ 
        color: red;
    }


/*CSS EDITAR USUARIOS.php*/

.notItemOne option:first-child 
{

display: none;}

/*CSS eliminar_usuario.php */

.link_delete 
{
    color: red;
}
.link_edit{
  color:    #00aae4;
}
.data_delete{ 
    text-align: center;}
    .data_delete h2 {
        font-size: 15pt;
    }
    .data_delete span{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #4f72da;
        font-size: 12;
}
.btn_cancel, .btn_ok{
    width: 124px;
    background: #478ba2;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 15px;
} 
.btn_cancel{
    background: #42b343;
} 

.data_delete form {
    background: initial;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    border: 0px;
}
/*CSS PAGINADOR*/
.paginador ul{
    padding: 18px;
    list-style: none;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 18px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.paginador a, .pageSelected {
    color: #428bca;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 38px;}

    .paginador a:hover{
        background: #ddd;
    }
    .pageSelected{
            color: #fff;
            background: #428bca;
            border: 1px solid #428bca;
}
/*BUSCADOR CSS*/
.form_search {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -o-flex;
display: -flex;
float: right;
background: initial;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
  }  
.form_search .btn_search{
    background: #1faac8;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 10px;}


/* LISTA DE PRODUCTOS */

.img_producto img
{
width:  60px;
height:  auto;
margin: auto;
}


.prevPhoto {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/uploads/user.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    margin: auto;
}
.prevPhoto label{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.prevPhoto img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.upimg, .notBlock{
    display: none !important;
}
.errorArchivo{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #cc0000;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.delPhoto{
    color: #FFF;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: -10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#tbl_list_productos img{
    width: 50px;
}
.imgProductoDelete{
    width: 175px;
}
```

Comment: Yo no veo ningun botón con la clase `addproduct` en todo ese código.  ¿Donde esta?

Comment: Disculpa, el boton esta en el PHP de lista de productos tal cual addproduct. Aun asi, con todo no funciona y no aparece la modal, tu ayuda seria útil!!

Comment: mmm... ¿estas seguro?  Donde está el link Agregar la clase se llama `add_product` y en cambio, en el javascript esperais que se llame `addproduct`... Entiendo que ambos deben ser iguales para que pase algo, y ahora mismo son distintos... ¿lo veis o no lo veis?